# HTTP POST to Google Maps Geolocation API fails on NodeMCU

Tags: api, lua, maps, esp8266, nodemcu

I am using a Wemos D1 Mini board and try to get the boards location using its surrounding APs and the Google Maps Geolocation API. The board runs NodeMCU and is programmed in Lua.

This is my code so far:

```
function listap(t) -- (SSID : Authmode, RSSI, BSSID, Channel)
    body = {}
    body["wifiAccessPoints"] = {}
    for bssid,v in pairs(t) do
        this_m = {}
        this_m.macAddress = bssid
        table.insert(body.wifiAccessPoints, this_m)
    end

    ok, json = pcall(sjson.encode, body)
    if ok then
      http.post('https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyC4IZU8CEB0jvSblOHqYm********', 'Content-Type: application/json\r\n', json,
      function(code, data)
        if (code < 0) then
          print("HTTP request failed")
        else
          print(code, data)
        end
      end)
    else
      print("failed to encode!")
    end

end
wifi.sta.getap(1, listap)
```

The JSON it created looks good and I can make the request using Postman for example, but every time I run this script, the request fails. Any idea why?

Comment: fails how? it throws an error?

Comment: sad thing about nodemcu lua is that its not throwing an error rather than setting a code to -1 if the request itself failed, so I guess it might be a syntax error?

Comment: I can confirm this code runs just fine using the latest NodeMCU from the `dev` branch with SSL enabled.

Comment: @flexwie all good for you now?

Comment: Sorry for not coming back at you earlier! I played around a litte, did not get it to work with the dev branch, but got it working by using the frozen 1.5.4.1-branch with SSL enabled